# detect the color of text

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, text, colors

How to detect color from given text (image)? E.g. I've got this image

[image: text image]

You can clearly see the text color is black (rgb 0, 0, 0). This is how it looks when I zoom the image:
[image: zoomed text image]

Now we can see there are at least 5 different colors.. **How can I detect the color that human eye sees?** Obviously I might take the most common color from all pixels of the image (excluding the background), but this doesn't always work (e.g. on much smaller text size where the letters are actually 1-2 pixel thick such as:

[image: thin text issues].

Comment: Small hint: Use image formats that don't compress the image lossy. I assume you are using jpeg images? The file extention states that these images are PNG, but png is a lossless format
The colors you can see are compression artifacts.

Comment: Two ideas... both untested. Either use a morphological dilation of the white areas so the unhappily coloured edge pixels of the letters get eaten and made white. Or, do a skeletonisation of the letters so you only have the central, non-edge pixels and see what colour the pixels forming the skeleton are.

Comment: @SilverMonkey: this is frequently not due to "compressing", but the "painting algorithm" that paints "subpixels" and then compresses those itself.

Comment: "_but this doesn't always work (e.g. on much smaller text size)._" Could you provide an example of  what you mean? Is this because you captured too small area around the text? Of the font is so small that every pixel is actually "anti-aliased" into something blurry? Or is it something else?

Comment: @SergGr http://prntscr.com/mgob2t, not sure if I don't have got just low quality image

Comment: @SilverMonkey See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType

Comment: I think the best you can do is scan each line of the image looking for sequences of identical pixels (that aren't the background color). That will obviously work great for the "Text" example. With the "Search" example, it's a little bit uncertain. From what I see, the possible repeated pixels are on the center and bottom of the 'S', 'e', and 'a'.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thx, didn't know that, really thought this was a compression issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a histogram of the text-image (excluding the background of course).
2. Check if there is a significant and clear peak (you can decide thresholds yourself or empirically). If there is one, that's the colour you are looking for.
3. If there is no significant peak, which looks like the case in "Search" text, take an average of all the pixel's colour. Roughly, this should be faint (approximation) of the original colour. Now, list the colour of all the (insignificant) peaks and try matching one by one hue/colour of this average. The peak which has hue/colour closest to the average should be your candidate.

Happy coding

Comment: looks promising, should I create a 3d histogram or is there any other way?

Comment: Actually, it's not easy to choose one type of histogram. Instead, it needs some research. I will go for RGB and Hue both histogram. If performance is important Hue can be conditional i.e. for second step only.